# Use Microsoft OneNote sharing link without a Microsoft account

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I would like to share a OneNote 2013 notebook with a user who does not have (and does not want!) a Microsoft account.  I can create a "Sharing Link" in the notebook's "Share Notebook" options, and this link allows the user to open/edit the notebook on https://onedrive.live.com.  This works ok, but I would really like to find a way for the user to use his native desktop OneNote 2013 app with this shared notebook.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: did you find the solution? It's 2022 now and MS still requires sign in when opening share link

Answer (score 0):

Just use a file synchronization software, like Dropbox, Google Drive, Bittorrent Sync, etc., and create the Notebook in a directory shared by both of you.

Example with Dropbox:

User1 creates the Notebook in the shared folder: 
OneNote -> File -> New -> Computer -> Create in different folder ->

User2, wait for the files to sync, and just open the notebook: 
OneNote -> File -> Open -> Computer -> Browse -> c:\users\user2\dropbox\sharednotes\ -> select Open Notebook.onetoc2

Of course, if you are going to share a sensitive data you can always use another layer of security on top of the file sync software, like CryptSync.

Comment: This might be a workaround.  But I worry about just copying the whole file.  What about update conflicts?  Doesn't the native "sharing" capability in OneNote handle concurrency issues better than "just copy the whole file"?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do this without signing in (although I don't know why this is).

Not sure if this is the case, but the user might be under the assumption that creating a Microsoft account means they will need sign up for a live.com or outlook.com email account.  This is no longer the case, Microsoft now allows the use of any existing email address as a Microsoft account.  So it's really just signing up with an existing email and remembering one more password.

Answer (score 0):

User can create and share this like mentioned earlier only through OneDrive link which is generated by Microsoft one note if connected to OneDrive service and without login into the OneDrive/outlook account by either of the parties shared the file or received that particular file cannot open that oneNote in different PC local. This procedure is to secure the file, and that's how I conclude the answer. Thanks

As far as a Microsoft OneDrive user there's no way to do that any other way to bypass login. Even if someone found a way by third party malware I suggest it is not secure and I'm afraid there might be a chance of sensitivite data loss.